# Make a c# function non-private, mark it as final, or seal its declaring type

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings

I am maintaining some old C# code and cannot change its structure too much. I tried to reduce some existing compiler warnings in a safe manner. Certain functions gave me the following warning:

> Warning   CS0108 'Function(string, string)' hides inherited member 'xyz.Function(string, string)'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

I assume that hiding that inherited function was intentional as the software has been used successfully for a number of years now. I saw no harm in adding the "new" keyword to make this function declaration as

```
private new void Function(string parm1, string parm2)
```

The warning disappeared as expected, but this one appeared instead:

> Warning   CA2222 Make 'Function(string, string)' non-private, mark it as final, or seal its declaring type. This method was originally defined in base class 'BaseClassName'.

Apart from suppressing this warning I am not sure what is the safest (i.e. non-behaviour changing) option available to me? I don't think that I should make this method non-private (which I assume means "public"). I am not sure how to make it final or sealed and whether or not doing so would be the right solution.

Comment: Can you give some more detail of the class with the original warning (use new keyword...) and the class it is extending? It sounds as  the original intent was most likely to mark the original function as virtual and the extended function as override. I need more detail to be sure though.

Comment: may be it was "protected" function in base class?

Comment: This is the method definition in the base class which the above code is hiding:

 public abstract class BaseCodeListPage<TMasterPage> : BasePage
      ...
    
  protected void AddOnClientClick(string parm1, string parm2) 
  {
  ...
  }

Comment: ...and the class definition, which contains this problematic func, is as follows:

 public partial class myListPage : BaseCodeListPage<myPage>

Comment: So, yes, as Yuri suspected, the function is protected in the base class. I am not sure if it is safe to touch it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is access to this method via reflection, remove the "new" keyword and then rename it (changing any calling site too). The method is private anyway, so it should only be in use from the same class unless it is being passed by delegate (then the name doesn't matter) or if reflection is used to access it.

Under the assumption that the code is correct, any calling of this method is intentional. Although I would review them and check if there could be any mistake by which the calling sites were calling the wrong method.

---

Any change to the visibility of the method is problematic, so avoid doing that※. About making the class [`sealed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx), it is also a breaking change because there may exist third party code that inherits form the class, so avoid that too.

※: Reductions of visibility are worst because there may exist third party code that uses the member, so that's a breaking change. Increasing visibility (for example making a private method protected or public) may break the encapsulation of the type, exposing a member may allow third party code to mess with the state of the objects of that type, so be cautious.

Comment: Thanks, this is good to know, but starting renaming methods or anything else is probably beyond the scope of what I can do now. Fortunately there aren't any third applications using this code.

Comment: @JouniJuntunen in that case you can leave the warning for now, it will be a reminder to look into it by you or by somebody else. Another thing, look into version control (so you can branch and try different solutions), an automated testing (so you can quickly do regression tests), those should mitigate any fears you or your coworkers may have when modifying the code.

Comment: Yes, I think that I leave it for now. It's not as much a fear of breaking things, but cost of touching the code in the first place. We have just revived this old code and work on some enhancements, which aren't very invasive and complicated. While I was familiarising myself with the existing code I though that I might make it a bit cleaner and easier to work with by removing at least existing some warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the warning - It's incorrectly being triggered. That said, `private new` is somewhat of a code smell, and may indicate a deeper problem.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182332.aspx) for an explanation as to why it occurs. It's worried that someone will come along and override your `new` method.

> If you must change the access modifier, either the **method should be marked final** or its type should be sealed to prevent the method from being overridden.

However, methods in C# are final by default. Marking a method as sealed (aka final in other languages) C# only prevents *further* overrides.

The warning would only be applicable if your new method were:

```
public/protected/internal virtual new void Function(string parm1, string parm2)
```

In which case the solution is to remove the `virtual` keyword

Comment: Thanks, this is very valuable information for a c# newbie like me.